# calculate combinations of letter-pair matches in two lists?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, comparison

I´m new to programming and can´t find a Q & A here that seems to be answering this exact question (although there are plenty on Python and matching words and letters in lists).

I have two lists like this:

```
  list1 = ["INTJ","ENTJ","ESTJ"]
  list2 = ["INTP","ESFJ","ISTJ"]
```

There are totally 16 possible combinations of letter-pairs. I've managed to calculate how many exact matches there are of letter-pairs, such as I/E (first), S/N (second), T/F (third) and P/J (fourth).

How can i keep track of how many exact 3-letter, 2-letter and 1-letter matches there are? Here are axamples of variants of three-letter matches:

```
 ISTP and ISTJ (I + S + T)
 INFP and INTP (I + N + P)
```

I´ve gotten help from user @thkang with counting the number of letter-pair matches like this, but I can´t figure out how to re-arrange this code to keep track of combinations of matches. Do I have to store matches some other way in order to accomplish this?

```
matches = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0}

for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
   for i in xrange(4):
      if item1[i]==item2[i]: 
      matches[i] += 1

total_letters_compared = #length of a list * 4
total_correct_matches = #sum(matches.values())
nth_letter_pair_matches = #matchs[n-1]
```

This is the code I've written, but I've come to understand that it is just plain bad code. Can someone help me get this right?

```
matches = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0}
four_letter_matches = 0
three_letter_matches = 0
two_letter_matches = 0

for item1, item2 in zip(actual, typealyzer):
if item1[0:2] == item2[0:2]\
or item1[0], item1[1], item1[3] == item2[0], item2[1], item2[3]\
or item1[1], item1[2], item1[3] == item2[1], item2[2], item2[3]\
or item1[0], item1[2], item1[3] == item2[0], item2[2], item2[3]:
    three_letter_matches = three_letter_matches + 1 

    elif item1[0:1] == item2[0:1]\
or item1[0], item1[1] == item2[0], item2[1]\
or item1[0], item1[2] == item2[0], item2[2]\
or item1[0], item1[3] == item2[0], item2[3]\
or item1[1], item1[2] == item2[1], item2[2]\
or item1[1], item1[3] == item2[1], item2[3]:
    #and so forth...
        two_letter_matches = two_letter_matches + 1 

    #I think I can get the one-letter matches by matches[1] or matches[2] or matches[3] or matches[4] 
for i in xrange(4):
    if item1[i]==item2[i]: 
        matches[i] += 1
```

I want to be able to print out the three-, two- and one-letter matches separately, somehow

```
print str(three_letter_matches)
print str(two_letter_matches)
print str(one_letter_matches)
```

Comment: jung / briggs myers personality test... MBTI ;)

Comment: Could you show the desired output for your example above? What are the 16 combinations of "letter-pairs"? What constitutes a two-letter match?

Comment: @isedev - correct. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools as IT
import collections

list1 = ["INTJ","ENTJ","ESTJ"]
list2 = ["INTP","ESFJ","ISTJ"]

matches = collections.Counter()
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    for n in range(1,4):
        for idx in IT.combinations(range(4), n):
            if all(item1[i] == item2[i] for i in idx):
                print(item1, item2, idx)
                matches[n] += 1

print(matches)
```

yields

```
% test.py
('INTJ', 'INTP', (0,))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (1,))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (2,))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (0, 1))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (0, 2))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (1, 2))
('INTJ', 'INTP', (0, 1, 2))
('ENTJ', 'ESFJ', (0,))
('ENTJ', 'ESFJ', (3,))
('ENTJ', 'ESFJ', (0, 3))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (1,))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (2,))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (3,))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (1, 2))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (1, 3))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (2, 3))
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (1, 2, 3))
Counter({1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 2})
```

I included an extra print statement to show what is being found as a match.

```
('ESTJ', 'ISTJ', (2, 3))
```

indicates that the two lists match at indices 2 an 3 -- i.e. letters T and J.

```
Counter({1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 2})
```

indicates that there are eight 1-letter matches, seven 2-letter matches, and two 3-letter matches.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you can track all matching combinations as follows:

```
list1 = ['INTJ','ENTJ','ESTJ']
list2 = ['INTP', 'ESFJ', 'ISTJ']
import collections
import itertools
matches = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item1,item2 in itertools.product(list1,list2):
    match = ''
    for i in xrange(4):
        if item1[i] == item2[i]:
            match += item1[i]
    if len(match):
        matches[match].append((item1,item2))
```

where `matches` ends up as:

```
{'ITJ': [('INTJ', 'ISTJ')], 
 'EJ': [('ENTJ', 'ESFJ')], 
 'INT': [('INTJ', 'INTP')], 
 'J': [('INTJ', 'ESFJ')], 
 'STJ': [('ESTJ', 'ISTJ')], 
 'TJ': [('ENTJ', 'ISTJ')], 
 'T': [('ESTJ', 'INTP')], 
 'NT': [('ENTJ', 'INTP')], 
 'ESJ': [('ESTJ', 'ESFJ')]}
```

If all you want to do is count the number of occurrences of a given match, you can modify the code as follows:

```
list1 = ['INTJ','ENTJ','ESTJ']
list2 = ['INTP', 'ESFJ', 'ISTJ']
import collections
import itertools
matches = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for item1,item2 in itertools.product(list1,list2):
    match = ''
    for i in xrange(4):
        if item1[i] == item2[i]:
            match += item1[i]
    if len(match):
        matches[match] += 1
```

which gives:

```
{'ITJ': 1, 'EJ': 1, 'INT': 1, 'J': 1, 'STJ': 1, 'TJ': 1, 'T': 1, 'NT': 1, 'ESJ': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn´t clear enough in my question - the result of your answer is more specific than I was trying to accomplish now, but it will sure help me further down the path of learning! I was really wanting to aggregate the number of hits per 3, 2 respectively 1-letter combination only.